# Why does my radio button not clickable on desktop mode?

Tags: php, html

I am trying to add an input radio button but the no option is not clickable on desktop media query. It is working for my other media queries though

I can only think that the reason why it doesn't work is because I am not using an array. Do I need to have an array for two input radio buttons?The strange thing is that the two options are working in my other media queries.....

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1">
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>




<?php
include_once __DIR__.'/header2.php';
if(!$_SESSION['u_uid']) {
   echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0;url=index.php?ticket=notlogin'>";
   exit();
}
   if($_SESSION['u_permission'] == 0) {
       echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0;url=header2.php?ticket=nopermission'>";
       exit();
   } else {




include_once __DIR__.'/includes/dbh.php';

  if ($_SESSION['u_permission'] == 0) {
    $_SESSION['u_permission'] = '';
  } else {
    $_SESSION['u_permission'] = 'Admin';
  } 

       if ($_SESSION['u_moderator'] == 0) {
        $_SESSION['u_moderator'] = '';
       } else {

           $_SESSION['u_moderator'] = 'Moderator';
       }




  $reply = 'Reply';



$sql = "SELECT * FROM customers_enquiry;";

 $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
    //Prepare the prepared statement
     if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)) {
         echo 'SQL statement failed';
     } else {
    //Bind parameters to the placeholder
//       mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $_SESSION['u_uid']);
    //Run parameters inside database
       mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

       $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
       $resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);

       if ($resultCheck < 1) {
          echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0;url=header2.php?ticket=noticket'>"; 
          exit();
       } else {

        echo '<form action="ticket_reply.php" method="POST">
             <table class="ticket">
             <tr>
             <th colspan="2" class="update_title">Ticket</th>
             </tr>';
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

       if ($row['solved'] == 0) {
         $row['solved'] = 'No';
       } else {
         $row['solved'] = 'Yes';
       }


             echo '
             <tr><th>User ID:</th><td>',htmlspecialchars($row['user_uid']),'</td></tr>
             <tr><th>Ticket No:</th><td>',htmlspecialchars($row['ticket']),'<input type="hidden" name="ticket" value="',htmlspecialchars($row['ticket']),'"></td></tr>
             <tr><th>First Name:</th><td>',htmlspecialchars($row['first_name']),'</td></tr>
             <tr><th>Last Name:</th><td>',htmlspecialchars($row['last_name']),'</td></tr>
             <tr><th>Subject:</th><td>',htmlspecialchars($row['subject']),'<input type="hidden" name="subject" value="',htmlspecialchars($reply),'"></td></tr>
             <tr><th>Mail From:</th><td>',htmlspecialchars($row['mailfrom']),'</td></tr>
             <tr><th>Message:</td></th><td>',htmlspecialchars($row['message']),'</td></tr>
             <tr><th>Date Submitted:</th><td>',htmlspecialchars($row['datesubmitted']),'</td></tr>
             <tr><th>Date Replied:</th><td>',htmlspecialchars($row['datereplied']),'</td></tr>
             <tr><th>Solved:</th><td>',htmlspecialchars($row['solved']),'</td></tr>
             <tr><th>View Message:</th><td>',htmlspecialchars($row['view_reply']),'</td></tr>
             <tr><th>Replied By:</th><td>',htmlspecialchars($row['replied_by']),' ',htmlspecialchars($_SESSION['u_permission']),' ',htmlspecialchars($_SESSION['u_moderator']),'</td></tr>';


           }

         echo '<tr><th>Has this been Resolved?</th><td><input type="radio" name="resolve" value="Yes"><label id="yes">Yes</label><input type="radio" name="resolve" value="No"><label id="no">No</label></td></tr>
              <tr><th></th><td><textarea name="reply"></textarea></tr></td>
                <tr><th>Add Reply/Message</th><td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Reply"></tr></td>


         <div class="ticket_ending">
         </div>';


         }

         echo ' </table>
             </form>';
}
}
```

When I clicked on the radio button, it doesn't do anything and there is a google translate button appearing above it...

Comment: What does media queries means?

Comment: None of your code is inside your `<body></body>`. Move `</body></html>` to the end of your page and see if that helps.

Comment: It doesn't work for the desktop version

Comment: **Side note**: you didn't even start the session. If you did it in `header2.php`, it's incorrect, as HTML has been outputing before your session start. Last, never use `include_once`, use `require_once` instead, as it will fire PHP error (and halt the script) instead of warning when your included files are missing.

Comment: Your HTML & PHP codes are malformed. Please double check your syntax. Put your PHP script block back into `<body>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

**I cannot comment, that's why I am answering your question !**

If you use IE on your desktop to test your application, it could cause the problem (using IE itself is not a problem), some times different elements get on top of each other and the second element become unclickable !

Maybe you can test with another non-Microsoft browser, or check in your browser console (F12) if the elements are properly placed, try adding z-index to your non-clickable radio button and check if it work.

- As mentioned in comments, put your codes inside body tags,
- In the question title you asked about *input type button*, but you explained about radio buttons, try to edit your question too,
- Just a suggestion, your code (PHP, HTML) is not well formatted, try to learn how write clean code and respect codding standards, it will help you solve your problems easier,

Comment: Relax, man. You will soon have enough points to post as comment. Your suggestions are helpful for OP.

Comment: thanks for the advice guys... I have removed the closing html tags but still the no option is not clickable

Comment: I also do have session_start in header2.php

Comment: @piano0011 your problem probably has nothing to do with PHP because as you said, it works fine on other platforms.